# RAILS 4 First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

Hi I've got a problem with: "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty". Since I am Rails newbie its hard for me to use existing answers (still cant find my mistake) Please, take a look:

```
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/admin/categories/_form.html.haml where line #1 raised:

First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
Extracted source (around line #1):


= simple_form_for [:admin, @category], :html => {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f|
  .form-group
    = f.label :name, class: "col-sm-2 control-label"
    .col-sm-10
      = f.input_field :name, label: false, class: "form-control"
  - if @category.id.present?
```

Render :

```
= render 'form', :url => admin_categories_path(@category)
```

Controller:

```
class Admin::CategoriesController < AdminController

before_action :set_category, :only =>[:show, :edit, :destroy, :update]

  def index
    @categories = Category.all
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.json {render json: @categories}
    end
  end

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.json { render json: @category }
    end    
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)

    respond_to do |format|
        if @category.save
            format.html {redirect_to admin_categories_path, notice: 'Category created'}
        else
            format.html {render action: 'new', alert: 'Error while creating'}
        end
    end    
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update

    respond_to do |format|
        if @category.update{post_params}
            format.html {redirect_to admin_post_path, notice: "Category updated"}
        else
            format.html {render action: 'edit', alert: "Error while editing"}
        end
    end  

  end

  def destroy
    @category.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to admin_categories_path, notice "#{Category.title} deleted"}
    end
  end

  protected

  def get_category
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  def category_params
    params.require(:category).permit(:title, :body)
  end
end
```

Comment: is this happening when you're looking at the new or edit action?

Comment: it happens when i go to route:
/admin/categories/new

So post

Comment: the error is saying `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty Extracted source (around line #1):` so either `@category` is nil, or passing in `:admin` to `simple_form_for [:admin, @category]` is being evaluated to nil

Answer (score 0):

In your `before_action`, make sure the you have `:new` in the array. Right now you don't, so `@category` is not being set when you go to /admin/categories/new

Comment: It is being set, in `new` action itself.

Comment: You mean in the controller? 
If yes it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it.
Got a little new view on it:

So - It rendered categories controller in admin directory - which was empty